# Multiple blinking text in table

Tags: javascript

This javascript I've found on the internet. With this in my table I can only get the first textbox blinking, the next time I want another textbox blinking it doesn't work. I'm a beginner, thanks for your support.

I've tried a second variable in the javascript, I've also copied the javascript with a different id. Still no luck...

In head I've placed:

```
 <script language="javascript">
function blinktext() {
  var f = document.getElementById('announcement');
  setInterval(function() {
    f.style.visibility = (f.style.visibility == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden');
  }, 500);
}
</script>
```

In html I used:

```
<div id="announcement" class="rTableCell">
<span style="color: #99cc00;">groen</span></div>
```

I expect to have multiple boxes in my table to blink
My table is here: https://zappi.info/faq-howto/hub/42-led-referentie-tabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest not to use setInterval() for this simple job and just stick to CSS animation like this:

The elements that need to blink should include this line in their style...

```
 animation:Blink 2000ms linear 0s infinite none;
```

And then add this to your CSS section independently...

```
 @keyframes Blink{from{background:white;} to{background:black;}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to use CSS to get the right result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll` and `classList.toggle`

Also note we have added a CSS class to do our hiding of the element.
The `toggle` call will add if it is not present and remove is it is.

```js
function blinktext() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.announcement').forEach(e =>{
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(e);
    e.classList.toggle('hide');
  }, 500);
  });
}

// We use an event listener to only run our code once the HTML is 
// loaded and ready to be read.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  blinktext();
});
```

```css
.hide {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="announcement rTableCell">
  <span style="color: #99cc00;">groen</span></div>

<div class="announcement rTableCell">
  <span style="color: #99cc00;">groen</span></div>

<div class="rTableCell">
  <span style="color: #99cc00;">groen</span></div>

<div class="announcement rTableCell">
  <span style="color: #99cc00;">groen</span></div>

<div class="rTableCell">
  <span style="color: #99cc00;">groen</span></div>

<div class="announcement rTableCell">
  <span style="color: #99cc00;">groen</span></div>

<div class="announcement rTableCell">
  <span style="color: #99cc00;">groen</span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I am a newbie in this kind of things, I couldn't manage to get it to work. I put the javascript code in the head, but where do I put the second block of code ? What to put in the body ? Thanks for clarifying this to me !

Comment: Ok, if you are going to put in the head it needs a slight tweak. Notice the demo html now puts announcement as a class.

Answer (score 0):

for multiple its easiest to go with the class descriptor

```
<div id="announcement" class="rTableCell blinking">
<span style="color: #99cc00;">groen</span></div>

function blink(target){
    return function(){
         target.style.visibility = (target.style.visibility == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden');
    }
}

let blinkers=document.getElementsByClassName('blinking');
for(let blinker of blinkers){
   setInterval(blink(blinker), 500);
}
```

like this should work (you need the return function structure to have the correct reference in the method)